# Count all subscriptions of a subject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.reactive, reactive-programming, observer-pattern

I have a Subject where I subscribe methods that should be called when a determined event in a game happens.

```
public Subject<SomeEvent> TestSubject = new Subject<SomeEvent>();
```

Some instances subscribe to that Subject.

```
TestSubject.Subscribe(MyMethod);
```

My objective is to count how many methods have been subscribed to that Subject. I've seen some examples using Count() extension but I need an int as a return value so then I can use it somewhere else, and Count() returns an IObservable.

```
if (subjectCount > 0)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Is there any way to get the number of subscriptions on a subject or do I need to keep track of them manually (having a public int SubjectSubcriptions and adding 1 everytime I subscribe a method) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way would be to create your own implementation of ISubject with a wrapper around a subject.

```
public class CountSubject<T> : ISubject<T>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ISubject<T> _baseSubject;
    private int _counter;
    private IDisposable _disposer = Disposable.Empty;
    private bool _disposed;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _counter; }
    }

    public CountSubject()
        : this(new Subject<T>())
    {
        // Need to clear up Subject we created
        _disposer = (IDisposable) _baseSubject;
    }

    public CountSubject(ISubject<T> baseSubject)
    {
        _baseSubject = baseSubject;
    }

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        _baseSubject.OnCompleted();
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        _baseSubject.OnError(error);
    }

    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        _baseSubject.OnNext(value);
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);
        return new CompositeDisposable(Disposable.Create(() => Interlocked.Decrement(ref _counter)),
                                       _baseSubject.Subscribe(observer));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _disposer.Dispose();
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a nice and clean solution, will wait for some other solutions before accepting this answer. Thanks !

Comment: This isn't a bad solution, but `Subject<T>` is disposable so this implementation should also be `IDisposable>` and it should support disposing of at least the created subject.

Comment: Ironically, the `Count` isn't observable ;-)

Comment: @LeeCampbell true but in his question he specifically states he wants an int and not an observable. Btw thank you very much for intro to Rx. Was very helpful when learning Rx for me

Comment: @LeeCampbell that's what the LINQ method Count() returned, but I couldn't figure out a way to do anything usefull with it. I just need a integer. Is there a way to get it out of that observable ?

Comment: I just being tounge in cheek. The `Count()` operator will return you a an observable sequence the represents the number of elements in the sequence (not the number of subscriptions). To get the count, the sequence needs to complete, then count will yield a single value then complete.

Comment: It's definitely not the easiest way... look at @LeeCampbell answer

Answer (score 2):

I am curious if this is only for testing purposes or not. If so, then the Rx-Testing nuget package has the tools to give you this information.

e.g. you can validate the number of subscription in a unit test like this

```
TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
var obs = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
      ReactiveTest.OnNext(1, "foo"),
      ReactiveTest.OnNext(1000, "bar"),
    );

//Do some work that should add subscriptions.
Assert.AreEqual(expectedSubriptionCount, obs.Subscriptions);
```

Comment: Not testing purposes, it's needed for a game. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This is a great answer!!